# How to mount macOS High Sierra on VirtualBox(Mac Host)?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos-highsierra

I have installed VM Virtualbox on my MacBook with Mojave. My objective is to install macOS High Sierra on a VM. Post creating the VM and attaching the ISO image, once the VM starts it is stuck in EFI shell before installing/Booting with High Sierra. Can someone please help me out?

[image]

Comment: maybe you could run startup.nsh from the efi shell? 

Comment: it automatically runs it in the EFI shell. You can check the image posted by me.

Comment: Where did you get the ISO image?

Comment: I converted the DMG to an ISO image in the terminal using hdiutils

Comment: Where did you get the DMG file

Comment: from Apple check this site - 
https://support.apple.com/en_AU/downloads/macos%2520High%2520Sierra

Comment: You can see from the screenshot that no filesystem is recognised by the UEFI firmware - you have `BLK0:` and `BLK1:` block devices but no `FS0:`, `FS1:`etc filesystems. Try connecting ISO to IDE instead of SATA controller, if this doesn't work post VBox version and hdiutil/createinstallmedia parameters you used.  See also [Installing Catalina OS in VirtualBox](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382367/115093)

Comment: I am using Vbox 6.1.6(latest version) and I used   'hdiutil convert ~/Desktop/InstallSystem.dmg -format UDTO -o ~/Desktop/HighSierra.iso'